# Space before bracket

Tags: xml, coding-style

While this has no impact, as far as I know, on processing the file, I've always wondered what the conventional approach is to the use of spaces before the closing bracket of an element tag. I've seen hundreds if not thousands of XML documents in my time and have yet to see a real pattern.

So I would like to know which of the two following notations would be preferred, if such a consensus exists.

`<element attribute1="value1" attribute2="value2">`

`<element attribute1="value1" attribute2="value2" >`

I realise that this may be a trivial question, but it would help me reach some consistency in my XML documents. I've noticed that the documents I've created through the years tend to switch between these two styles. Whenever I create a new document, I usually end up wasting a minute on deciding which style to use, so I welcome input on what style I should finally settle on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't format XML manually.

For example: http://www.xmltoolbox.com/

Actually, don't format any source code manually. Computers are great at repetitive tasks, and can format XML with 100% consistency. Decide on a style you like and program the computer to do it.

That said, you rarely see `<element attribute="value" >` in XML documents. Most browsers, as another example, will cinch up the closing angle bracket for XHTML source.

Comment: I don't generally format my code manually but as you say, you have to decide on what style to use. Still, you make a valid point for that most browsers will omit it, which would probably make it a de facto standard.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'm fine with

```
<element attribute1="value1" attribute2="value2">
```

but when it's `/>`, I prefer

```
<element attribute1="value1" attribute2="value2" />
```

May be to make it more visible, more meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer no white space.

```
<element attribute1="value1" attribute2="value2" >
```

The reason is that the whitespace at the end creates an unbalanced look, since the opening tag is not spaced from the text. Again either way will work for you, but in the name of symmetry use:

```
<element attribute1="value1" attribute2="value2">
```

Or just to make it even more confusing use the following option:

```
< element attribute1="value1" attribute2="value2" >
```

Comment: The last option might not actually work, it's more there for comedic effect.